# ¿Cómo extraigo el número mayor y menor que el usuario introduce en la lista?

Tags: python, pycharm

```
num = int(input('¿Cuántos números vas a introducir?: '))
cont=0
media=0
listaNumeros = []
while num>0:
    division=num
    num=num-1
    numeros=int(input("Dime un número: "))
    listaNumeros.append(numeros)
    if numeros<0:
        cont=cont+1
    media+=numeros
    media=media/division


print('El número mayor es el %s')
print('El número menor es el %s')
print('Se han introducido %s números negativos' % cont)
print('La media aritmética es: %s' % media)
#print('%s' % listaNumeros)
```

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción si no estas limitado en cuanto a que características del lenguaje puedes usar, ya que usas un iterable puedes recurrir a las funciones preconstruidas  `max`, `min`, y `sum` para hacer lo mismo simplifando el código.

```
num = int(input('¿Cuántos números vas a introducir?: '))
listaNumeros = []
for _ in range(num):
    numero = int(input("Dime un número: "))
    listaNumeros.append(numero)

print('El número mayor es el {}'.format(max(listaNumeros)))
print('El número menor es el {}'.format(min(listaNumeros)))
print('Se han introducido {} números negativos.'.format(sum(n<0 for n in listaNumeros)))
print('La media aritmética es: {}'.format(sum(listaNumeros)/num))
print('La lista completa es:\n', listaNumeros)
```

Si no vas a validar la entrada o cualquier otra cosa que haga necesario usar un `while` cambia el ciclo por un `for`, es mas eficiente.

[Ejecución en IDE online](https://repl.it/MIqU/0).

Answer (score 0):

Crea una variable llamada `mayor` por ejemplo, y mira por cada número que introduzca a ver si es mayor al que contenga la variable.

Al final quedará el más alto entre todos los introducidos.
Lo mismo pero al reves para el `menor`.

```
num = int(input('¿Cuántos números vas a introducir?: '))
cont=0
media=0
mayor=0
menor=999999
listaNumeros = []
while num>0:
    division=num
    num=num-1
    numeros=int(input("Dime un número: "))
    listaNumeros.append(numeros)
    if mayor<numeros:
         mayor=numeros
    if menor>numeros:
         menor=numeros
    if numeros<0:
        cont=cont+1
    media+=numeros
    media=media/division

print('El número mayor es el ' % mayor)
print('El número menor es el ' % menor)
print('Se han introducido %s números negativos' % cont)
print('La media aritmética es: %s' % media)
#print('%s' % listaNumeros)
```